# Using Chef with OpenStack, what would encourage me to use Heat templates?

Tags: chef-infra, openstack

It feels like Heat serves some overlapping purposes, though it adds more orchestration than I can get with Chef out of the box today. Would the Heat template really only serve to document run lists?

Comment: I don't think the two are mutually exclusive.  You could use Heat to provision your OpenStack resources (networks, subnets, routers, security groups, cinder volumes, nova instances, etc), and then have it trigger chef in nova instances to complete your instance configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chef has drifted into the same functional space as heat with its new "provisioning" feature (formerly known as chef metal):

- https://docs.chef.io/provisioning.html

I would suggest trying both. Chef provisioning is more chef friendly and designed to work across multiple cloud technologies, whereas Heat is specific to Openstack. Ultimately this is what will influence your decision I think.